# Finding roots in polynomials of $Z/pZ$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find if $x^3 + x + 1$ has a root in the ring $F_{17}[x]/(x^3+x+1)$

So I get

$x^{17} - x = x(9x^2 + 12x+4) - x = 12x^2 - 6x - 9$

and then I do the Euclidean algorithm and get

$x^3+x+1 = (10x+5)(12x^2-6x-9) + 2x +12$

$12x^2-6x-9 = (6x-5)(2x+12)$

The answer solution stats that,  $gcd(x^{17}-x, x^3+x+1) = x+6$, where does the $x+6$ but where does the $x+6$ come from?

Also, it says that the unique root modulo $17$ is equal to $11$, but why is the root $11$? Is it because $x+6$ is equivalent to $11$ mod $17$?

Also, how do we know that there is only one root?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element of $\mathbb{F}_{17}$ satisfies $x^{17} - x = 0$ i.e. $x^{17} - x = x(x-1) ... (x - 16)$. Finding roots of $x^3 + x + 1$ is effectively trying to factorize $x^3 + x + 1 = (x - a) g(x)$. If $a \in \{0, ..., 16\}$ is a root of $x^3 + x + 1$ then $x - a$ must divide both $x^3 + x + 1$ and $x^{17} - x$; hence $x - a | \gcd(x^3 + x + 1, x^{17} - x)$. So if we know $\gcd(x^3 + x + 1, x^{17} - x) = x + 6$ by Euclidean algorithm, the only root can only be $-6 \equiv 11 \mod 17$.